# Cakephp mail is not sending to mail id

Tags: php, html, email, cakephp, ctp

In my code mail is not sending to mail id but the data is inserting into table
here am attaching my controller code

```
function supportrequest()
    {
        $heading = 'DATA CENTER SUPPORT';
        $this->set('heading', $heading);

        if(!empty($this->data))
        {
            $this->data['SupportRequest']['date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $this->data['SupportRequest']['supportId'] = 'SRID-'.$this->uuid();
            $SRID = $this->data['SupportRequest']['supportId'];
            $this->data['SupportRequest']['name'] = strtolower($this->data['SupportRequest']['name']);
            $this->data['SupportRequest']['status'] = 'Open';
            //print_r($this->data);
            /*$adminurl = "https://www.antzmedia.com/admin/supportrequestlogin/sid:".$this->data['SupportRequest']['supportId'];
            $message  = "You have a new support request from a customer. Please follow the below link to see the support request.<br/><br/>";
            $message .= $adminurl;


            //$to = "marvil@antzmedia.org";
            $to         = "support@antzmedia.org";
            $subject    = "Support Request Entry";
            // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
                      ."Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"
                      ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
                      ."From: =?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode($this->data['SupportRequest']['name']) ."?= <".$this->data['SupportRequest']['email'].">\r\n"
                      ."X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);*/

            $userurl    = Router::url('/', true)."home/supportrequeststatus/sid:".$SRID;
            $to2        = $this->data['SupportRequest']['email'];
            $subject2   = "Support Request Info";
            /*$message2   = "You have received this mail because you have made a support request to Antz Media.<br/>
                           Your concern has been registered and our support team will be in touch with you soon.<br/>
                           This is your Support Request ID : <b style=color:green>".$this->data['SupportRequest']['supportId']."</b><br/>
                           Use this ID to track the progress of your queries.<br/>
                           Please follow this url to get your support request status : ".$userurl."<br/><br/>
                           Thankyou.";*/

            $message2 = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" border="0" width="600"  style=" background:#B9FFEF; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; ">
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><strong>Greetings From CTL !!!</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#333333;">Your query has been successfully submitted.</td>
                    <tr >                                       
                    <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#333333;">Your Support Request ID :<font color="green"><b>'.$this->data['SupportRequest']['supportId'].'</b></font></td>
                    </tr>                   
                    <tr >   
                    <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#333333;">Use this ID to track the progress of your query. Our Technical Support Team will surely assist you to resolve your concern.</td>         
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr >
                    <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:13px; color:#333333;">Click <font color="blue">'.$userurl.' </font>to check your status.</td>                                    
                    </tr>                                    
                    </table>';             


            $headers2 = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
                      ."Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"
                      ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
                      ."From: =?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode("CTL") ."?= <admin@noreply.com>\r\n"
                      ."X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();

            mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $headers2);

            if ($this->SupportRequest->save($this->data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('<br/>Support Request has been submitted successfully.<br/><br/>
                 Your Unique Support Request ID ( <b>'.$SRID.'</b> ) has been sent to your E-mail.<br/><br/>
                 For further updates,please check your E-mail Inbox / Junk Folder or our website regularly.<br/><br/>','default',array('class' =>'successbox'));
                $this->redirect('/home/supportrequest');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Something went wrong please try again after refreshing the page.','default',array('class' =>'errorbox'));
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried many email id's but the same is happening...that means no mail is send to mail id provided....

Comment: which version of cakephp you are using? and have you enable mail in php.ini?

Comment: Cakephp Version is 1.3.8

Comment: have you enable mail in php.ini?

Comment: Am running it in remote..then how can i enable it in php.ini

Comment: try simple send mail script and check mail send working on this server or not

Comment: am not an expert in php or cakephp...am an intermediate level programmer in C# desktop applications...So i dont whether the given program is hard or simple...So is there any bug in this code

Comment: Please define $address here

Comment: $address means email of send or reciever

Comment: <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:11px; color:#333333;"><strong>Address</strong></td>
                          <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:11px; color:#333333;">'.$address.'</td>

Comment: $address is already exists in the code

Comment: hello  Er.KT ...actually the problem happens in the support request not in contact form..sorry

Comment: i will post the code for support request....

Comment: Please post it in your question not in comment,so other can help you

Comment: function supportrequest()
 {
  $heading = 'DATA CENTER SUPPORT';
  $this->set('heading', $heading);
  
  if(!empty($this->data))
  {
   $this->data['SupportRequest']['date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $this->data['SupportRequest']['supportId'] = 'SRID-'.$this->uuid();
   $SRID = $this->data['SupportRequest']['supportId'];
   $this->data['SupportRequest']['name'] = strtolower($this->data['SupportRequest']['name']);
   $this->data['SupportRequest']['status'] = 'Open';

Comment: $userurl  = Router::url('/', true)."home/supportrequeststatus/sid:".$SRID;
   $to2   = $this->data['SupportRequest']['email'];
   $subject2  = "Support Request Info";

Comment: $message2 = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" border="0" width="600"  style=" background:#B9FFEF; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; ">
     <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><strong>Greetings From CTL !!!</strong></td>
     </tr>
     <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#333333;">Your query has been successfully submitted.</td>

Comment: <tr >          
     <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#333333;">Your Support Request ID :<font color="green"><b>'.$this->data['SupportRequest']['supportId'].'</b></font></td>
     </tr>     
     <tr > 
     <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#333333;">Use this ID to track the progress of your query. Our Technical Support Team will surely assist you to resolve your concern.</td>   
     </tr>
     <tr></tr>
     <tr >

Comment: <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:13px; color:#333333;">Click <font color="blue">'.$userurl.' </font>to check your status.</td>           
     </tr>          
     </table>';

Comment: $headers2 = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
       ."Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"
       ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
       ."From: =?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode("CTL") ."?= <admin@noreply.com>\r\n"
       ."X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
       
   mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $headers2);

Comment: if ($this->SupportRequest->save($this->data))
   {
    $this->Session->setFlash('<br/>Support Request has been submitted successfully.<br/><br/>
     Your Unique Support Request ID ( <b>'.$SRID.'</b> ) has been sent to your E-mail.<br/><br/>
     For further updates,please check your E-mail Inbox / Junk Folder or our website regularly.<br/><br/>','default',array('class' =>'successbox'));
    $this->redirect('/home/supportrequest');
   }
   else
   {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Something went wrong please try again after refreshing the page.','default',array('class' =>'errorbox'));
   }
  }}

Comment: oh my friend please dont post in comment update your main question.your main question

Comment: Okay sorry.. i will paste it there

Comment: Hello  Er.KT ... Atlast i got it..Now the mail is working properly...You helped me a lot...The issue is that i have coomented one code...Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just check mail send working or not on your server try following code in one file and save this file(let's say testmail.php) in webroot and check it on yourdomain.com/testmail.php

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

I can not put this answer in comment so thats why I have posted here

Comment: I got the message Mail Sent

Comment: good means mail send working on your server now problem with your cakephp code

Comment: What happens when i edit "0" to "1" or "2" in the code write('debug', 0)

Comment: its the debug level, it will display errors,warning in php script,set it to 2

Comment: $message2 = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" border="0" width="600"  style=" background:#B9FFEF; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; ">
     <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><strong>Greetings From CTL !!!</strong></td>
     </tr>
     <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#333333;">Your query has been successfully submitted.</td>
     <tr >          
     <td style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#333333;">Your Support Request ID :<font color="green"><b>'.$this->data['SupportRequest']['supportId'].'</b></font></td>
     </tr>